# Namespace not found only when trying to build the app (Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, compiler-errors, namespaces, assemblies

I'm currently developing an app for android. In my code, I use the namespace UnityEngine.XR.WSA.WebCam. When I'm launching the app on the editor, I have no errors, but when I try to build this to send it to my phone, I get the following one :  `The type or namespace name "WebCam" does not exist in the namespace "UnityEngine.XR.WSA". Are you missing an assembly reference?"` Isn't it strange since it's working on the editor? How do i fix it?

Answer (score 4):

"WSA" in the namespace stands for "Windows Store Application" -- so unless you're targeting a Windows Phone, it won't build.

You must be running the editor on a Windows machine, so that's why it works there.

(Also, frankly, I'm very uncertain of how well Windows Phone is supported anymore, so even if you got it to build, it still might not run or do what you're hoping for.)